# C++ bindings for MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, binding

I'm running OSX(10.4.11) & I'm trying to get a decent C(preferably C++) binding for MySQL figured out. I have some data in an offsite database I want to analyze.

I'm trying to get MySQL++ working, but it's being funky.

I'm looking for other bindings, preferably ones with a no-headache install.

edit:

MySQL has C bindings. Clunky and low-level, but it works(after some library fiddling).

http://www.sqlapi.com/ supports Solaris/Windows/Linux.

Comment: -1: I don't understand how to answer this question.

Comment: Whoops. I assumed you'd read my mind. Why do you not have a mind-reading facility installed?

Comment: Can you clarify why MySQL++ won't work for you?  It's a pretty good solution.

Comment: @Runcible, I don't remember anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Connector/C++ is a C++ implementation of JDBC 4.0

The reference customers who use MySQL Connector/C++ are:
- OpenOffice - MySQL Workbench

Learn more: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,221298

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLApi++](http://www.sqlapi.com/) has been ported to OS/X by [this guy](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/realbasic/plugin-sql.shtml), as part of a REALBasic plugin.  He may be open to licensing it.

I don't know why it hasn't been licensed back to them. Maybe they are not interested in supporting Mac clients.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net). Although it builds upon the MySQL C API, it presents a much nicer C++-friendly interface than using the C bindings.

Answer (score 0):

There is mysql++. I've used it with one of our c++ projects.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've used mymysql in the past (still do if I'm working in C++) it's a lightweight wrapper around the C api and ties memory management to object lifetimes.

It can be found here: http://www.redi.uklinux.net/mymysql/

Despite the warnings on the site, it's still not a bad library.  It was actually written by a former colleague and despite him not really maintining it anymore it's still in fairly good shape.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had any problems using the MySQL C library.