# how to read data from a MySql database in Visual Studio (c++)?

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I am new to databases , and I just have managed to connect a database to VS, but how can I read the information from a table line by line , and store it in a vector of strings for example so to be used in a program? (if this is possible of course)

Comment: You consume the appropriate libraries / interfaces for the task.

Comment: It is nearly unfathomable to imagine reading a MySQL database with a C++ binding is not covered anywhere. Of course, it could be covered *everywhere* and still not be found if you're not *looking*. [Did you search this site for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220756/c-bindings-for-mysql) ?

Comment: I did , it wasn't very  helpful

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Comment: This is a library question, not an IDE question. My tip would be: search for it in Google using https://www.google.com/search?q=dot+net+MySQL

Comment: I understand, thank you !